# How to buy a Gold ETF in India?

Tags: india, etf, gold, commodities

How can I buy a Gold ETF in India?

Are they the best way to invest in Gold, and are there any other options?

Answer (score 2):

You can buy Gold ETF just like any other shares you buy, via your broker and an demat account.

It is one of the way to invest in Gold rather than Physical. Search this site and you will have answers.

If you don't have a demat account, you can also buy Gold based Mutual Fund